# Iterate through a column to give input to a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a process I'm dealing with that seems a little abnormal, at least in a MySQL context.

I have a temp table of unknown size. It consists of only a single column, called ID.

I am using this column of IDs to input a value to a stored procedure.

It basically goes like this:

```
SET @ID_var = (SELECT ID FROM temp_pidn);

CALL some_stored_proc(@ID_var);
```

My system works fine, but only if the temp table has one column and one row.

I'm trying to scale this up: what if the temp table has 2, 3, or n rows. I would like to call `some_stored_proc` 2, 3, or n times, all in a row.

In my mind, I see the need to iterate down a column, in a loop-like manner, calling a stored procedure in series. I feel like this could be pretty straightforward in Python or (especially) R, but in MySQL world, I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: First answer in the above question should give you what you want.

Comment: Oh my god. This is horrible. Cursors? MySQL is even more archaic and clumsy than I realized. Regardless, thank for pointing me in the right direction.