# MySQL Stored Procedure - Split JSON Type field to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, json, loops, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL version 5.7. 
I have a table with JSON field named `json_text` as below (this is one record example):

```
[
{
company: A,
users: [
        {
            userID: 1,
            userName: "Jane Doe 1"
        },
        {
            userID: 2,
            userName: "Jane Doe 2"
        },
        {
            userID: 3,
            QuestionText: "Jane Doe 3"
        }]
}]
```

Each company will have different number of users. What is the best way for me to transform the above json field into table as below:

```
Company userID userName
A       1      "Jane Doe 1"
A       2      "Jane Doe 2"
A       3      "Jane Doe 3"
```

I am thinking of doing two WHILEs like the code snippet below but I don't know if this is good for performance or there are better and clearer way to do this:

```
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE number_of_users INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE userID INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE company VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE userName VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE json_text JSON;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO
    SET number_of_users = 0;
    SET company = '';
    SELECT JSON_LENGTH(json_text) FROM test_table LIMIT i, 1 INTO number_of_users; 
    SELECT json_text FROM test_table LIMIT i, 1 INTO json_text; 
    SELECT Company FROM test_table LIMIT i, 1 INTO company; 
    SET x = 0;
    WHILE x  <= number_of_users DO
        SET userID = 0
        SET userName = 0
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, CONCAT('$[', x, '].userID')) INTO userID
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, CONCAT('$[', x, '].userName')) INTO userName
        INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (Company, userID, userName) VALUES(company, userID, userName)
    SET x = x + 1
    END WHILE;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Is there any better way to do this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: which mysql verion you are using ?

Comment: Using a cursor instead of  `COUNT()`, the outer `WHILE` and repeated `LIMIT i,1` might be better.  I created all the necessary boilerplate code needed for using cursors -- with substantial comments explaining why each line was needed -- in [this frankly amazing yet sad and lonely, underappreciated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35927643/1695906) here on SO and discussed it again later in [an answer at dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138553/11651).  In those cases, what the OPs wanted to do inside the loop was call another proc, but it's equally applicable here.

Comment: Hey @Michael-sqlbot could you please add in the answer so I can mark it as correct. Thank you.