# How does HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND work and what is its usage?

Tags: mysql

Still kinda new to MySQL. I was wondering what is HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND, how does it work and most importantly: what is its usage?

Comment: You might try Google. Take a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HANDLER` is for catching exceptions.

When reading from a cursor, reading past the end of the cursor throws a `NOT FOUND` exception, rather than returning an endless stream of `NULL`, so you have to catch this exception.

```
DECLARE val1 INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM t1;

-- when the NOT FOUND condition fires, "done" -- which defaults to FALSE -- will be set to true,
-- and since this is a CONTINUE handler, execution continues with the next statement.   

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN c1;

my_loop: 
LOOP

  FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO val1; 
  IF done THEN -- this will be true when we are out of rows to read, so we go to the statement after END LOOP.
    LEAVE my_loop; 
  ELSE
    -- maybe do more stuff here
  END IF;
END LOOP;

-- procedure continues here...
```

Copied in part from my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927643/1695906).